# Why portainer can not run successfully in docker of windows server 2016?

Tags: docker, portainer

I followed this tutorial:https://www.portainer.io/2019/09/deploying-portainer-on-a-pure-windows-2019-swarm-cluster/

Here is the code:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker --version
    Docker version 19.03.5, build 2ee0c57608
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="cluster_management" dir=in action=allow protocol=TC
    P localport=2377
    Ok.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="node_communication_tcp" dir=in action=allow protoco
l=TCP localport=7946
Ok.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="node_communication_udp" dir=in action=allow protoco
l=UDP localport=7946
Ok.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="overlay_network" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP l
ocalport=4789
Ok.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="swarm_dns_tcp" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP loc
alport=53
Ok.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="swarm_dns_udp" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP loc
alport=53
Ok.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> curl https://downloads.portainer.io/portainer_windows_stack.yml -o portainer_windows_stack.ym
l
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker stack deploy --compose-file=portainer_windows_stack.yml portainer
Updating service portainer_agent (id: vi5cvjv2wq8ery10p5s4stw05)
Updating service portainer_portainer (id: ykjjq98r2zrtlfdhzgqu1j6gq)
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
NAMES
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS
       PORTS               NAMES
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

[image]

All codes ran without any error. Why the portainer does run now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with this.

However, I followed an unofficial tutorial:https://airdesk.com/2017/10/windows-containers-portainer-gui/

And it finally works.